# Help with appendTo() jquery function on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I am a beginner, so keep that in mind.

so what I currently have working is my form successfully adds another input to the form, however it appears out of the form div. Basically I want it to appear within the div and above the submit button.

how do I do this?

here is main appendTo in my javascript:

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1; 
$('a#add').click(function() { 
    $('<input type="text" value="user' + i + '" />').appendTo('form'); 
    i++; 
});
```

here is the form html as on request.

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form name="addstudents" method="post" action="add_students.php">
<div id="formHeader">
    <h1>Add student(s)</h1>
    <p>Please enter student's HEMIS number</p>
</div>
<label>Student: <span class="small">Enter HEMIS number</span> </label>
<input type='text' name="user_1">
<input type="submit" class="Mybutton" id="mybutton" name="submit" value='Submit Student(s)'>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
<a href="#" id="add">Add</a><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

NEW PROBLEM: REMOVING!

here is my current remove JS, it simply removes the submit button first :(

```
$('a#remove').click(function() { 
if(i > 3) { 
    $('input:last').remove(); 
    i--; 
}
});
$('a.reset').click(function() {
while(i > 2) { 
    $('input:last').remove(); 
    i--;
}
});
```

Thanks again

Comment: How does the markup look? (I.e., does it make sense to append to the `<form>` element or is there a `<div>` or something within?)

Comment: Another thing: If you're using PHP, you don't need to keep track of `i`. Instead, you can name all the `<input />` field `user[]` and then access the `$_REQUEST['user']` as an array.

Comment: Does the form element need to be specified with a class name or id to make it work?

Comment: the form div is this `<div id="stylized" class="myform">`

Comment: @jensgram, I don't quite follow?

Comment: @buymypies It's just that if you don't need the sequence number (`i`) but only a list (array) of all the `name=user*` inputs, you can name them `name="user[]"` and PHP will give you `$_REQUEST['user']` (or `$_GET['user']` or `$_POST['user']`) as an array of all the values submitted.

Comment: @jensgram, how would I extract it though, to say run it in a query?

Comment: @buymypies Instead of doing `$i = 1; while (isset($_POST['user_' . $i])) { ...; $i++; }` (or the like) you can just `foreach ($_POST['user'] as $user) { // $user = value from each input }`. Disclaimer: This may not be suitable in your case. Just to let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet to insert the input before the button:

```
$('form #idofsubmitbutton').before($('<input type="text" value="user' + i + '" />'))
```

**EDIT:**

I played around with [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/exstac/UhAyj/1/) after your last edit and came upp with this:

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
$('a#add').click(function() {
    $('div#stylized form input:submit').before($('<input type="text" value="user' + i + '" />'))
    i++;
});
```

With the example html you posted this works. When I press the add link new inputs appear before the submit button.

If you still got problems you might have elements with duplicate ids.

Comment: @jjross im still struggling to get it to even appear within the form div, i tried `.appenTo('#stylized')` with the html being  `<div id="stylized" class="myform">` but no luck.

Comment: @buymypies could you paste the form html into the question so we can have a go at it? :)

Comment: @buymypies I have edited my response to reflect your latest edit

Comment: ok i did get it working a different way (i created a new div n separated the submit button from that div). However my new problem is, removing, now when I remove it simply removes the submit button first. :(

Comment: note it is the same situation after implementing your code. I have added remove code to inital post

Comment: @buymypies if you add [type="text"] to you selector it will only delete inputs of type text. Full example: $('input:last[type="text"]').remove();

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1; 
$('a#add').click(function() { 
    $('<input type="text" value="user' + i + '" />').appendTo('div#divId'); 
    i++; 
});
```

Comment: do u specify it within the div or class? so mine is like this: `<div id="stylized" class="myform">` ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking here, but this is the correct way to do what you want. Assuming that you have a <div> with id "divID" that contains your form fields but NOT your submit button, this should work. Change the ID to match the actual ID of your div.

Comment: ye but my submit is within my form div and I want the input to be inserted above the submit.

Comment: basically, following this guys code ive now got `.appendTo('div#stylized');` and it still does exactly the same as before

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "PHP form", once it's on the client, it's just HTML/CSS/Javascript. PHP is on the server.

`.appendTo('form');` appends to the form TAG, not a "form div". If you have a DIV named "form" you need to use `.appendTo('#form');`

Comment: dno why i called it a php form my bad.

Comment: but how to insert it above the submit button?